# SFML GQE game engine, std::move and unique_ptr's, c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

So I have this problem with SFML and C++11.

I'm following the book that explains the development of a game engine using SFML. I'm a decent ways along, changing the code minutely here and there to get it to work for my project.

I'll try and summarize the big picture: In the part of the book that discusses the generation of a World Object, we need to build the scene that will get drawn by the World's draw function. we do this in a buildScene() function.

The objects that are drawable to the screen are SceneNodes. SceneNodes have sf::Drawable and sf::Transformable, which allow them to be drawn to the screen. Inside of the SceneNode class, we have a std::unique_ptr<SceneNode> Ptr, as a way to have a quick reference to a SceneNode for some functions.

attachChild is one of these SceneNode functions. When a SceneNode is drawn or updated, it draws/updates itself, then its children.

```
void SceneNode::attachChild(Ptr child)
{
        child->mParent = this;
        mChildren.push_back(std::move(child));
}
```

I'm very unfamiliar with move semantics, and the std::move function. I know it has to do with something about not copying memory and staying efficient, and also something about type casting, but I'm very new to c++ so its hard to follow the documentation.

Anyways, inside of buildNode(), we construct our entities like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<Player> player(new Player(mTextures));
mPlayer = player.get();
mPlayer->setPosition(mSpawnPosition);
mPlayer->setVelocity(0.f, 0.f);
mSceneLayers[Air]->attachChild(std::move(player));
```

The last line is the problem. attachChild seems to want a SceneNode::Ptr object, but the book's source code uses the code above, and I'm assuming that it works for them.

```
||=== Project2, Debug ===|
C:\Users\Game\Documents\CodeBlocks Workspace\Project2\Game\classes\World.cpp||In member function 'void World::buildScene()':|
C:\Users\Game\Documents\CodeBlocks Workspace\Project2\Game\classes\World.cpp|62|error: no matching function for call to 'SceneNode::attachChild(std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<Player>&>::type)'|
C:\Users\Game\Documents\CodeBlocks Workspace\Project2\Game\classes\World.cpp|62|note: candidate is:|
C:\Users\Game\Documents\CodeBlocks Workspace\Project2\Game\classes\..\headers\..\..\engine\headers\SceneNode.hpp|19|note: void SceneNode::attachChild(SceneNode::Ptr)|
C:\Users\Game\Documents\CodeBlocks Workspace\Project2\Game\classes\..\headers\..\..\engine\headers\SceneNode.hpp|19|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<Player>&>::type {aka std::unique_ptr<Player>}' to 'SceneNode::Ptr {aka std::unique_ptr<SceneNode>}'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Here is the error. Also, here is the link to the tutorial book's source code: [here](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML-Game-Development-Book)
The source code is organized by chapters, anything after chapter 3 should have the code I'm looking at (inside of World.cpp and the Aircraft files, which is like my Player)

Comment: Looking at the source for chapter 7, `Aircraft` derives from `Entity` which derives from `SceneNode`. I'm guessing you've messed up the inheritance hierarchy somewhere for your `Player` class. It must derive from `SceneNode`, either directly, or indirectly through one of its bases, for the code above to compile.

Comment: Would be nice if anyone of you guys could make it an actual answer, so it can get marked as solved.